# Where to see a list of available and unavailable privileges?

Tags: support, privileges

I have tracking the 'Next privilege' in the user profile, but have no list of available privileges, like list of badges. Is it possible to see it somewhere?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can view the list of privileges in the help center:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: You can also get there by clicking the trophy icon(rep drop down) and clicking on the privilege link on the top.